# Combine multiple POST arrays

Tags: php

I have a POST php form in which I have 2 repeating fields.

Since the fields are repeating, I'm using these names `field_1[]` and `field_2[]` in the html code to get an array.

Then with PHP I'm imploding the array data like this:

```
$field_1 = implode('-', $_POST['field_1']);
$field_2 = implode('-', $_POST['field_2']);
```

And then I combine the data this way:
`$result = $field_1 . "-" . $field_2;`

So if user inputs `banana`, `orange`, `cherry` in the first fields and `5`, `10`, `3` in second fields, I'm getting something like:

```
banana-orange-cherry-5-10-3
```

Now my question is, how can I get it like this

```
banana-5
orange-10
cherry-3
```

?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: You want them as array elements or as string.

Comment: Is there anything stopping them entering different numbers of values in each type?

Comment: You could rename your form elements to something like: `name="field[1][name]"` and `name="field[1][count]"` and increment the number for each pair (`field[2][name]` and so on). Then the data in the `$_POST`-array will be more structured and grouped and easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `foreach` one of the arrays and concatenate elements with the corresponding elements from the another array.

```
foreach($_POST['field_1'] as $key => $value){
    $_POST['field_1'][$key] = $value.'-'.$_POST['field_2'][$key];
}
```

and in `$_POST['field_1']` you'll have

```
banana-5
orange-10
cherry-3
```